# Bevel mess over UV Sphere

Tags: mesh, bevel

Liam trying to achieve a vibe over this uv sphere and a cylinder as I did over a cube but when I apply the bevel it messes up the mesh. suggestions welcomed!

thanks!

[image: Bevel mess over UV Sphere]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A subdivision approach would be to let Catmull-Clark do your bevelling

Start with a level of subdivision lower than the one you want to wind up with, and cheat if you can: choose the number of segments in your sphere to fit your chimney profile nicely. Retain a highly-subdivided copy of the sphere in the same place, as a future Shrinkwrap target. Hide it if you like.

Create a 6 or 8-sided circle to be the profile of the chimney, raise it above the sphere, position and orient the profile over the sphere

[image]

Knife-Project the circle down on to the sphere

[image]

<kbd>X</kbd> Delete the faces created by the projection, and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> copy the edges on the perimeter of the hole: raise them in Z and scale to 0 in Z to flatten. Select all the vertices on the surface of the sphere, and create a vertex group from them. Assign a Shrinkwrap modifier to that group, with the intact subdivided copy of the sphere as target.

<kbd>J</kbd> or <kbd>K</kbd> Cut some edges in the sphere joining the 'loose' vertices of the hole to existing sphere vertices, creating convex polygons, not too skinny or irregular, but don't worry about making all quads.. we're going to let the first level of subdivision do that for us.

[image]

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > Bridge Edge Loops between the hole and the profile, and Catmull-Clark subdivide the whole model once with a Subdivision modifier under the shrinkwrap. We're almost done.  (You can use Loop Tools > Circle to make the profile regular.) If you apply this first level of subdivision, you're all quads. Selecting loops to slide them around becomes easier.

[image]

The rest is tweaking, smoothing, Because of the Shrinkwrap, you can move vertices around on the surface of the sphere quite a bit without disturbing its curvature. If you were really fussy, you could create a shrinkwrap target for the chimney, too. The sharpness of the bevel can be altered by sliding / adding / removing edge loops in its vicinity.

[image]

Comment: Woow Thnks Robin!! all clear!

Comment: thank you very much for taking the time for such a detailed answer, I have done all the steps pretty straight forward but I am trying to understand  why you used the Shrinkwrap modifier and assigned it to the vertex group and targeted to the sphere? Thanx Robin!

Comment: (The shrinkwrap is to the intact copy of the sphere, of the verts you want to stay spherical) . It's true, you may not strictly need the shrinkwrap. But if you wanted to  keep near-perfect sphere curvature, and have the freedom to move vertices around near the bevel, to ease it, without worrying so much about introducing bumps or ripples... it's a generally useful technique in modeling .. used a lot with cars, and suchlike.